# Calculate minimum significant difference with LSD.test (agricolae) with unequal group observations

Tags: r, anova, tukey

I am attempting to follow the example from LSD.test on my data set. Unfortunately, my data set has unequal sample sizes, I have read that this can be handled by a weighted mean; does anyone have experience with this? Is there a way to calculate this outside of the function?

Here is my example code:

```
library(agricolae)

data <- as.data.frame(c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10), rep("D", 11)))
data$Value <- c(59.15,48.90,29.65,32.60,63.85,53.85,66.40,55.05,54.75,39.95,63.20,57.40,59.15,54.10,49.40,78.70,66.20,90.75,
                81.20,52.25,53.70,51.10,48.60,50.15,63.40,56.15,38.40,66.45,53.35,45.30,46.60,53.20,53.95,44.55,49.15,42.65,
                68.25,67.60,57.90,47.85,52.90)
colnames(data) <- c("Treatment", "Value")

cal <- lm(Value ~ Treatment, data = data)

model<-aov(cal)

out <- LSD.test(model,"Treatment", p.adj="bonferroni")
#stargraph
# Variation range: max and min
plot(out)
#endgraph
# Old version LSD.test()
df<-df.residual(model)
MSerror<-deviance(model)/df
out <- with(data,LSD.test(Value,Treatment,df,MSerror))
#stargraph
# Variation interquartil range: Q75 and Q25
plot(out,variation="IQR")
#endgraph
out<-LSD.test(model,"Treatment",p.adj="hommel",console=TRUE)
plot(out,variation="SD") # variation standard deviation
```

This is still "working" however not listing the "Minimum significant difference" as in the typical example:

```
library(agricolae)
data(sweetpotato)
model<-aov(yield~virus, data=sweetpotato)
out <- LSD.test(model,"virus", p.adj="bonferroni")
#stargraph
# Variation range: max and min
plot(out)
#endgraph
# Old version LSD.test()
df<-df.residual(model)
MSerror<-deviance(model)/df
out <- with(sweetpotato,LSD.test(yield,virus,df,MSerror))
#stargraph
# Variation interquartil range: Q75 and Q25
plot(out,variation="IQR")
#endgraph
out<-LSD.test(model,"virus",p.adj="hommel",console=TRUE)
plot(out,variation="SD") # variation standard deviation
```

Edit 1:I have also tried using unequal groups with HSD with agricolae, however this returns an error:

```
data(sweetpotato)
A<-sweetpotato[-c(4,5,7),]
modelUnbalanced <- aov(yield ~ virus, data=A)
outUn <-HSD.test(modelUnbalanced, "virus",group=FALSE, unbalanced = TRUE)
```

Error in HSD.test(modelUnbalanced, "virus", group = FALSE, unbalanced = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (unbalanced = TRUE)

Edit 2: I have now used the group=FALSE command to find the individual interactions:

```
      difference pvalue signif.        LCL        UCL
A - B -14.820000 0.0301       * -28.664094 -0.9759055
A - C  -2.245000 1.0000         -16.089094 11.5990945
A - D  -3.557727 1.0000         -17.083524  9.9680696
B - C  12.575000 0.0943       .  -1.269094 26.4190945
B - D  11.262273 0.1554          -2.263524 24.7880696
C - D  -1.312727 1.0000         -14.838524 12.2130696
```

Now how would I find what difference = p =0.05? I have looked at a linear relationship between the three p values that aren't equal to 1, and the root square of the difference. The relationship isn't perfect but it is strong R2 = 0.98, likely an effect of the sample sizes.

[image]

Could I use this to predict what the least significant difference would be @ p = 0.05? Or am I completely misguided?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: A couple comments: First, if the group sizes are unequal you can't have just one minimum significant difference, as that difference depends on the group sizes. Also check the help for HSD.test; the error message is telling you that unbalanced is not a valid argument. Finally, you might also check out the emmeans package; I've switched over to it almost exclusively for these kind of analyses.

Comment: Thanks Aaron will check out that package also, please see edit 2!

Comment: As I said, the minimum significant difference depends on the group size, so you can calculate it exactly for each particular pairwise difference, if you wanted to. But that will tell you the same information as the p-values. So more importantly, it's not clear to me why you want this number or what scientific question would be answered by it. You already have the results that typically are used to answer most scientific questions from data like this.